# Does coding in Node js differ from coding using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I happened to use a coding platform which didn't give the option to write code in JavaScript but rather gave node as an option. I don't have much experience in Node , so just wanted to know if I could proceed writing the code in pure JavaScript and not face any issues?

Comment: Node.js is a JavaScript runtime, so yes, you write JavaScript for node.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript doesn't get you very far; you need APIs provided by the host environment to allow for most forms of input and output. I mention this because a lot of people confuse "Pure JS" with "JS + Browser supplied APIs".

The APIs provided by Node.js are different to the APIs provided by the runtimes in browsers (the most obvious difference being that if you are writing for a web browser then you'll have a DOM generated by an HTML document to manipulate by default).

That said, there aren't many pure JS features that Node.js lacks.

The only one I can think off of the top of my head is that ES6 modules are not enabled by default since Node.js implemented CommonJS modules before ES6 modules had been added to the specification. You have to [enable ES6 modules explicitly](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) if you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a popular runtime for Javascript. It is one of the ways to run javascript. It's not 'impure' (depending on your definition on pure/impure).

Answer (score -1):

Pure Javascript (Javascript code that does not rely on any libraries that are not defined in the ECMAScript standard) will run in any Javascript environment such as a browser or nodejs that supports the version of ECMAScript you are targeting.

But, pure Javascript can't really do much on its own because it has no display, no file system, no networking, etc...  To get some of those things, you need a supporting Javascript environment that has it's own APIs for those types of things.

The supporting environments are generally not compatible.  For example, if you want to make an http request to another host, you do that completely differently when running in nodejs versus when running in a browser though you can get a library for nodejs that simulates some browser APIs such as `node-fetch` simulates the `fetch()` interface from the browser.

So, it really depends upon what you're trying to do.  If a coding platform specifies node, then that's probably because that coding platform relies on other APIs that are specific to node and you will need to use node.  For more specific details, we would need to know what the environment is and what the coding project is.